# css transform:rotate(xdeg) puts element always in foreground

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, transform

[i have 2 Pictures,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM8ys.png)
and i want to rotate the cursor.

Works fine, but my nav bar is fixed, and the image(cursor) is always on [top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJuSp.png) of the navbar.

this is my Code:

```
[0].head1 { // navbar
[1]  position:fixed;
[2]  min-width:100%;
[3]  margin-top: 3rem;
[4]  z-index:14;
[5]}
[6]#cursor{ // cursor
[7]  margin-top: -48px;
[8]  transform: rotate(180deg);
[9]}
```

i have tried, to play around with the z-index, of my cursor, and tried all the position possibilities. If i remove line 8 in my code, it works perfectly fine, except for the roation..

my html is: (i know all this head1, head2 etc. is not nessesary, i will change later.

```
<div id="head1" class="head1">
    <div id="head2" class="head2">
      <div id="head3" class="head3">
        <p id="blabla" class="blabla">......</p>
        <div id="head4" class="head4">
          <p id="text" class="text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="blend">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <div style="min-height:13rem;"></div><!-- Spacer-->

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="detailEntrie"><strong>2012</strong></br>2013</td>
        <td class="detailEntrie"><strong>116i</strong></br>320d</td>
        <td class="detailEntrie"><strong>Juli</strong></br>September</td>
        <td class="detailEntrie">
          <p>Drivable?</p>
          <img src="assets/images/drivablemeter.png" alt="Driveable?" style="width:100px;">
          <img id="cursor" src="assets/images/drivablecursor.png" alt="Driveable?" style="width:100px;">

        </td> 
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: edited, but theres nothing special, thats why i didnt include it, in the beginning

Comment: Can you also give us the images? The problem might be, that cursor is not absolute. You want to place the cursor above the "drivable" isnt it?

Comment: http://glascake.com/testpublish/ you can find the full page here, this will be deleted in a few weeks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any z-index specified to the fixed .head1
Make sure to put at least

```css
.head1 {z-index: 1}
```

to the fixed navigation. Note, z-index: 14 is present in your original code, but on your real page example - it is absent

Comment: thank you, but why is it working if i write the style inside the HTML, but the style is already in my css, and it will not work

Comment: ah, I see there is a syntax error. In fact you should not use '//' comments in CSS and instead just use '/* comments */'. So either replace or remove in your CSS this code http://prntscr.com/j8z1zg